# Regex match line except word with special character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get package dependencies from `apt-cache depends` output and try to remove "Depends:", "Recommends:", "Suggests:".

```
$ apt-cache depends gdebi
gdebi
  Depends: <python3:any>
    python3:i386
    python3
  Depends: gdebi-core
  Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.91
  Depends: python3-gi
  Depends: gksu
  Depends: gnome-icon-theme
  Recommends: libgtk2-perl
  Recommends: shared-mime-info
    shared-mime-info:i386
  Recommends: lintian
```

What I've tried is using this pattern but it can only remove the words only without the colon ":"

> (?!Depends: \b)\b.+

What have I missed? How do I get it using `grep -P` only?

The output should be like this.

```
<python3:any>
python3:i386
python3
gdebi-core
gir1.2-gtk-3.0
gir1.2-vte-2.91
python3-gi
gksu
gnome-icon-theme
libgtk2-perl
shared-mime-info
shared-mime-info:i386
lintian
```

Comment: What program are you using this regex with?

Comment: I use the grep -P regex. But other language like javascript quite similar  regex pattern compare to perl, so I think languages won't be a problem. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "grep only" requirement is odd and self-defeating, but since you insist: If we can assume that a package's name won't have any spaces in it, this will do:

```
apt-cache depends gdebi | head -n +2 | grep -o '\S\+$'
```

The `-o` flag makes grep print only the parts of the lines that match.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#bY9PC4JAEMXvfYo5BB5kJBWiIjr1CerqxT/TuujOyroFQt/d1BJc6Tjvx3tvXm9TWQMy@BG8QRhqADV4yT3xt17fi4IyuQG4UkNctCc4N50tNcenlLvLAABmQcaH/VJYuqYYzLUhR5UmDCIUtsI42P0hL0sYBcdwiX7pKJy3RNU@nZu1IpS5ZrQlqbH2RrlW6otrmQ2tETZk6hVqy9RQgUqOfn7oadJanMe6mWxlyh8)

#### Original answer

This is a good task for the standard unix tool [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
apt-cache depends gdebi | sed -re '1d; s/^ +((Depends|Recommends|Suggests): )?//'
```

The sed code has two parts:

1. `1d` deletes the first line.
2. `s/^ +((Depends|Recommends|Suggests): )?//` replaces any text matching the regular expression between the first two slashes with the text between the last two slashes (which in this case is an empty string).

The `-r` flag tells sed we're using [extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE), which just means we don't have to escape special characters (in this case, `(`, `)`, `+` and `?`) with a backslash.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#bU9BDoIwELz7ir0hMQsCiVE0evEFejcBupYG25K2mpj4d0QiEYi33ZmdmZ3GEgM0BF7EtmDDCyzm8yPVpJh9najQUnbj@c45WWf9FPxDGHpNwxnlYgbwPU5hVz9dqVWSZuq5bwmAHhDJejUEhqrOBgttaIQKEwUxcldhEiz/MA9HGAebaEh93ZGP3uKVvY92pSWhKLRCV5L8xP56pnATeZsaY03mNqFsmRliKMVHr666qzQF@7JjT@VEpt4)

Comment: I expect using the universal regex, so I can better understand what I miss.

Comment: @AlvinPutra There's no such thing as "universal regex," but sed is a standard unix tool and the above uses [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04), just like grep.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a little more context. As unix tools go, sed is about as "universal" as they get.

Comment: sorry but what I meant like PHP, Javascript, and grep Perl which have almost same special characters like they have the same '\w', or lookahead like 'x(?=y)'.
I edited the question more specific, using grep -P only.

Comment: your sed code has answered my question before I edit my question, so I think I should mark your answer. Thanks. Also I've just found the solution by myself using regex. `apt-cache depends gdebi | grep -Po '(?<=Depends: |Recommends: |Suggests: |\s+)(?!.+[:<>]).+'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with multiline flag:

Find:

```
^(\s*((Suggests)|(Recommends)|(Depends)):)?\s*(.*)$
```

Replace:

```
$2
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/CuaosB/3

Regex:

`^(\s*(?:(?:Suggests)|(?:Recommends)|(?:Depends)):)?` Look at the start of line for this pattern 0 or 1 time and capture as group 1

`\s*` Consume spaces after the first pattern.

`(.*)$` Select everything after the first pattern till the end of line and capture as group 2.